# sprite problem with image link

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink, sprite

how to use sprite with image links. when i try to use as below link lost

```
<a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" title="link1" href="http://www.yahoo.com">
    <div id="yahoo1" class="logosprite"></div>
 </a>
```

css:

```
#yahoo1.logosprite {
background-position:0 0;
height:16px;
width:16px;
}
```

can anyone suggest better solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not valid markup.

Simply apply the CSS to the anchor  and add the following css property so that it is the right size:

```
display: block;
```

Answer (score 1):

`a` elements cannot contain `div` elements.

Just set the background image on the `a` itself.